# check | or || regex

Tags: java, regex

This is sample string that I want to split. I am using `string.split("\\|")` . But as the string itself has double pike character, I am getting "" for that .

I want to check to split the string with pike `|` OR double pike `||`.

```
aaa|bbb|ccc|ddd||eee|iii||
```

Comment: For the record, it's called a *pipe* character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
string.split("\\|\\|?")
```

The `?` makes the second pipe optional.

You may also want to use:

```
string.split("\\|+")
```

which is "one or more `|`" in case you have more than two in a row.

Answer (score 2):

You could specify an occurrence range:

```
"aaa|bbb|ccc|ddd||eee|iii||".split("\\|{1,2}")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex instead:-

```
String regex = "\\|\\|?";
str.split(regex);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string.split("\\|{1,2}");
// A pipe ------^ ^ ^
// once           | |
//      or twice    |
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regex: `String[] splits = yourString.split("[|||]+");`The + after treats consecutive delimiter chars as one. You may please remove the plus if you do not want this. Example is shown below:

```
public class RegexTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String yourString = "aaa|bbb|ccc|ddd||eee|iii||";
        String[] splits = yourString.split("[|||]+");
        for (String split : splits) {
            System.out.println(split);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: wat's the need of 3 pipes in the character class?